# What is the difference between these SQL statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This statement works:

```
DECLARE @variable_name INT

SET @variable_name = (SELECT DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE()))

SELECT *
FROM   artists
WHERE  SUBSTRING(DOB, 0, 5) > '1900'
       AND CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB)) = @variable_name
```

This one doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM   artists
WHERE  SUBSTRING(DOB, 0, 5) > '1900'
       AND CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB)) = 
                        (SELECT CONVERT(INT, datepart(DAYOFYEAR, getdate())))
```

it returns the error

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

This one works

```
SELECT * 
FROM artists 
WHERE DOB IS NOT NULL
  AND SUBSTRING(DOB, 0, 5) > '1900' 
  AND convert(int, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB)) = '100'
```

Today happens to be the 100th day of the year

and I don't understand why, I am using SQL Server 2008.

The column is set as `varchar(10)`. I have dates in there going back to the 1700's

Date format in the table is

```
1930-04-10
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I can put both queries in the same window, highlight and run one at a time against the same data set. And get the above results.

Comment: `SUBSTRING(DOB, 0,5)`  Is `DOB` a string?

Comment: It looks to me that this is [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). And you try to compare two dates. If you want to skip time part/check if it is user birthday  there are easier methods. Please provide sample data and desired result.

Comment: Can we assume these both are running against the exact same data set (Database.schema.table?)  The nature of the error indicates that DOB is a string which the database  is unable to parse a day of year from; due to it being in an invalid format.  Since the queries are IDENTICAL up to that point really... that leaves me with the conclusion, you must be running against different data sets.

Comment: @xQbert It's not about an invalid format, it's about an out-of-range value, according to the error message. Given that the OP has values going back to the 1700's, and `datetime`'s minimum value is 1753-01-01, that makes sense. What also makes sense is seemingly equivalent queries producing by chance a different query plan, causing the conversion to be skipped in one of the queries but not the other one (because the `SUBSTRING(DOB, 0,5) > '1900'` filters out those records already). What doesn't make sense to me though is that `datetime` is used at all.

Comment: @hvd passing the column to `datepart` will cause an implicit cast. There is no guarantee of the order of evaluation of the predicates.

Comment: @MartinSmith But `select datepart(year, '1752-01-01')` returns `1752` on SQLFiddle without any problem, suggesting a conversion to `datetime2` rather than to `datetime` when the value is of varchar type. Or am I doing something very wrong in my testing there?

Comment: @hvd - No that does seem to be the case thanks. And if it is outside the range of datetime2 the error message is `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` which is not the one stated.

Comment: What does `select @@version` return?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 17 2011 00:57:23   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 <X86> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Does the artists table have any computed columns?

Comment: No, it is all user data, nothing in the table is computed

Comment: The idea that in one query ` SUBSTRING(DOB, 0,5) > '1900'` is evaluated before the DATEPART expression so the latter doesn't get executed on some records, makes perfect sense to me. See if you get an error with `SELECT max(CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB))) FROM artists;`

Comment: What's the use of `CONVERT` here anyway? `DATEPART` returns an integer that you want converted to an integer? What the heck?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I tried the select suggestion you made and it comes up with the same error.     Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. As for why use convert, well, the statement started out differently and morphed into this due to frustration, I think it is not working on the order of precedence I think it should be, but that could be my lack of understanding.

Comment: There simply is no precendence. The DBMS may evaluate the substring expression first or the datepart/convert expression. It's totally up to the DBMS. We tell the DBMS what to check; the DBMS decides for the execution plan and order of criteria check. That my query fails, shows that there is at least one value in `DOB` that cannot be interpreted as a date. Check your values. Maybe select `MIN(DOB)` and `MAX(DOB)` first and see if these can be converted. Or you can look for special characters, blanks, etc. that don't belong in that column.

Comment: One stores dates in a database as dates, not as strings, of course - or there is some good reason against it. Is there a reason you store the date in `DOB` not as `DATE` but as `VARCHAR(10)`? Maybe you sometimes don't know a part of the date of birth and leave it blank? This can be done with a string, but not with a year and would thus be a good reason to use a string for storage. On the other hand this would lead to incomplete dates and `DATEPART` would fail on these, naturally.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for the replies, there are artists with no DOB, which are nulls. a check for MIN(DOB) returns 1414-01-01, and MAX(DOB) returns 2015-05-30. All values in the column are either null or valid data entries matching the format, what you say about there being no order or precedence stacks up with the results, I didn't know that, my ignorance I know, and now I am wiser for asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

In both queries you are checking two conditions:

```
SUBSTRING(DOB, 0, 5) > '1900'
```

and

```
CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB)) = some integer;
```

The DBMS decides which one to check first. Obviously in your first query, the DBMS checks the first expression first, thus ruling out some `DOB` that couldn't be converted with `DATEPART`. But the second query checks the second condition first and fails trying to convert some value.

**My advice:** Your best bet would be to change your table and have the DOB stored as `DATETIME2` rather than `VARCHAR(10)`.

If this cannot be done for some reason, You can force precedence of the first condition over the second by using a subquery (derived table):

```
select *
from artists
from
(
  select *
  from artists
  where substring(dob, 1, 4) > '1900'
) after_1900
where datepart(dayofyear, dob) = datepart(dayofyear, getdate());
```

This works (hopefully), but isn't completely proper. For example a `DOB` can still contain an invalid date, such as '2016-XY-??' or simply '2016-02-30'. And in the `DATEPART` expression you treat `DOB` as a `DATETIME` which it is not. Implicit conversion takes place, which can easily fail.

Here is a query with a check for the right date format first and an explicit string to date conversion:

```
select dob, name
from
(
  select convert(datetime2, dob + ' 00:00:00', 120) as dob, name
  from artists
  from
  (
    select dob, name
    from artists
    where dob like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
  ) valid_data_strings
) converted
where datepart(year, dob) > 1900
and datepart(dayofyear, dob) = datepart(dayofyear, getdate());
```

Still, this doesn't solve the 30th February problem, though. I don't think there is an easy way to detect valid date strings and only consider these records then. Possible, yes, but certainly some work with all that leap year logic needed.

As mentioned, it would be much easier to change the table design instead.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, but still strange.

This statement doesn't work

```
SELECT * FROM   artists WHERE  SUBSTRING(DOB, 0, 5) > '1900'
AND CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB)) = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, datepart(DAYOFYEAR, getdate())))
```

This one does

```
SELECT * FROM   artists WHERE  SUBSTRING(DOB, 0, 5) > '1900'
AND CONVERT(INT, DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, DOB)) = (CONVERT(INT, datepart(DAYOFYEAR, getdate())))
```

by removing the Select from the get current date section, the statement springs to life, this can only mean that the addition of the "Select" (which actually makes no difference), changes the order of precedence, which makes sense in a convoluted way. But I would argue is a bug.